# Is "Updated On" date on WHO.IS is affected by change in a DNS notes (changing servers)?

Tags: dns, whois

so the question is: Is "Updated On" date on WHO.IS is affected by change in a DNS notes (changing servers IP address)? Or "Updated On" is just about changing the registrar information only?

And if it's indeed affected, how long does it take for the changes to be seen on WHO.IS?

Comment: Great question. I expect this depends on the registrar and is tld/cctld specific. ICANN has a document which does not answer the question  but implies some answers at https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/approved-with-specs-2013-09-17-en#whois - ie it shows the answer to be registrar specific and changes must be reglected within 7 days.. (usually 1 day) - but it is silent on the Updated field, and  of-course only applies to ICANN controlled domains.  The whois specification itsel is very promitive and does not have any requirements.